# Get all AD users not in parent group

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have a group that I use named staff.  It is a parent of a few nested groups.  I need to audit the group to list the users who aren't a part of that group or any nested child groups within it.  I have found scripts that will give me the users who aren't part of the Staff group, but it doesn't include any of the child groups so a user could be part of the child group but still be listed as not being in the parent group.  I don't want to have to script that for each child group of the parent.

Is there any way to list all accounts that aren't part of a group but also all of it's children?

Comment: Of course there is a way. By modifying the script. 
Get the list of all child groups and select users not in those groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a single LDAP query like that by using what it called the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` operator.
The numeric OID for this operator is `1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941`. You request this type of option in the LDAP search by placing the numeric OID between the attribute and the value you are searching for `(attribute:OID:=DN)`. You can run LDAP queries with the PowerShell cmdLet like this:

```
get-adobject -ldapfilter "(&(objectcategory=person)(objectclass=user)(!memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=some,CN=group,DC=yourco,DC=com))"
```

This query also uses the not (!) operator as you are looking for users who are not a nested member of the group. You can also run LDAP queries through ADUC/DSA by selecting "Custom Search" and the "Advanced" tab.[image: gui search]

Two MS articles that cover this and some other details on LDAP search syntax that makes this possible:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/914828/a-hotfix-is-available-that-improves-the-performance-of-programs-that-q
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks for the info about the OID, and the links as well.  Super helpful!